# Navigation Drawer - ошибка при переходе на другою Activity

Tags: android

При создании Navigation Drawer реализовал слушатель нажатий на его строки, но попытавшись через интент перейти на другое активити выкидывает ошибку.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] drawermenu = {"Афиша","Расписание","Брони","Акции","Контакты"};

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item,drawermenu));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerClickListener());
    }

    public class DrawerClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            switch (position)
            {
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
                case 3:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sales.class));
                    break;
                case 4:

                    break;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Вот логи.

```
05-12 10:39:21.911  32580-32580/com.cinema.west920.cinema E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cinema.west920.cinema, PID: 32580
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cinema.west920.cinema/com.cinema.west920.cinema.Sales}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at com.cinema.west920.cinema.Sales.onCreate(Sales.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно хочет, чтобы вы использовали тему `AppCompat` в запускаемой активити:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Лучшим решением будет назначить в манифесте эту тему всему приложению сразу:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.app" >

 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
 ...
</style>
```

От себя рекомендую вообще не заморачиваться самостоятельной реализацией `NavigationDrawer`, а воспользоваться [готовым решением](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer), это сэкономит вам много времени и нервов.

Answer (score 1):

В сообщении об ошибке предельно четко указанно почему она возникла и как это иправить:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`